# how to add category for laravel permissions?

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I created an application using the spatie permission package.
And I want to categorize the permissions as shown below, without using the package

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open `config/permission.php` and define all of the permission in it using nested array:

```
 'default_permissions' => [
      'product_management' => [
          'view_own_pro',
          'view_pro',
          'mng_own_pro',
          'mng_pro',
          'force_delete_pro',
          'restore_pro',
      ],
      'role_management' => [],
      'category_management' => [],
      'order_management'=> [],
      'user_management'=> [],
    ],
```

**Edit answer:**

Or use it more simply:

```
 'default_permissions' => [    
      // role_management  
      'view_role',

      // category_management
      'view_own_category',
      'force_delete_category',

      // user_management
      'view_user',
      'create_user',              

      // pro_management
      'view_own_pro',
      'view_pro',
      'mng_own_pro',
      'mng_pro',
      'force_delete_pro',
      'restore_pro',
    ],
```

And in routing:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['permission:view_user|view_role']], function () {
//
});
```

Or in blade:

```
@can('view_user')
  //
@endcan
```

Check [spatie-docs](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v4/basic-usage/middleware) for more info.

Comment: How do I call in the blade?